# From where can I find Grails/Groovy tool suite for working with Grails 2.1.0

Tags: grails

I am new to Grails/Groovy. I wanted to install GGTS for Grails 2.1.0.
Which version of GGTS I have to use and from where I can download that?

Comment: I don't know. You can go back as far as 2.3.2 at https://spring.io/tools/sts/legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Downloads are available at https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all, e.g. for Linux you would download [this](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.4.RELEASE/dist/e4.4/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.6.4.RELEASE-e4.4.2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz).